# Attempt to invoke interface method 'int android.database.Cursor.getColumnIndex(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, sqlite, android-studio, android-layout

I would really appreciate some help! I am working on a project and I am stuck at this part!

Log Cat:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int android.database.Cursor.getColumnIndex(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.workhours.NotesCustomAdapter.onBindViewHolder(NotesCustomAdapter.java:38)
    at com.example.workhours.NotesCustomAdapter.onBindViewHolder(NotesCustomAdapter.java:16)
```

Code:

```
     16)  public class NotesCustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NotesCustomAdapter.ViewHolder>{
     17)      private ArrayList<newNote> arrayListNote;
     18)      private Context context;
     19)      Cursor cursor;

     20)   public NotesCustomAdapter(ArrayList<newNote> arrayListNote, Context context) {
     21)        this.arrayListNote = arrayListNote;
     22)        this.context = context;
     23)    }

     35)    @Override
     36)    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
     37)        holder.notePadTextView.setText(arrayListNote.get(position).getNote());
     38)        long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBaseHelper.COL_0));
     39)        holder.itemView.setTag(id);
     40)    }
```

Comment: Your `cursor` object is null on line 38: `cursor.getColumnIndex`

Comment: Perfect. How do I fix that exactly! Thank you!